# chaining and getting the value of an input

Tags: jquery

This code gets the text that's in a certain column of a table row:

```
var keyA = $(a).children('td').eq(column).text().toUpperCase();
```

Q: How do I rewrite this to get the value of an input tag that's in the table cell?

```
var keyA = $(a).children('td').eq(column).('input').val().toUpperCase();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var keyA = $(a).children('td').eq(column).find('input').val().toUpperCase();
```

Answer (score -1):

Oh! It's:

```
children('input')
```

Comment: `children` looks for direct children in the element, `find` will look in all descendants.